# What are (empirically) sufficient conditions for NVCC to use ldg instead of normal loads?

Tags: pointers, caching, cuda, readonly, ldg

Section G.4.2 of the CUDA C Programming Guide [says](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-3-0):

> Data that is read-only for the entire lifetime of the kernel can also be cached in the read-only data cache described in the previous section by reading it using the `__ldg()` function ... When the compiler detects that the read-only condition is satisfied for some data, it will use `__ldg()` to read it. The compiler might not always be able to detect that the read-only condition is satisfied for some data. Marking pointers used for loading such data with both the `const` and `__restrict__` qualifiers increases the likelihood that the compiler will detect the read-only condition.

My questions:

- "Increases the likelihood" - why is the likelihood not 100% for `const __restrict__` pointers? After all, you really aren't allowed to use them for writing (unless you `const_cast` or something nefarious like that).
- What are, from your experience, sufficient conditions for the compiler using `__ldg()` itself on `const __restrict__` pointers?
- Conversely, in which situations should I explicitly use `__ldg()` for loads from `const __restrict__` pointers.

Comment: `__ldg()` requires that accessed data is read-only for the *entire life time of the kernel*. By contrast, `__restrict__` represents a promise the programmers makes to the compiler *for a particular function scope*. It is well possible that read-access data that is not aliased inside a given function is aliased to writable data further upstream in the call chain, which would make use of `__ldg()` unsuitable. Separate compilation, deep call chains with lack of function inlining, and pointer manipulation can prevent the compiler from establishing with certainty that `__ldg()` is safe to use.

Comment: @njuffa: Wouldn't the kind of aliasing you're suggesting break the 'contract' of `__restrict__`? Or - perhaps I'm misinterpreting what you mean by "further down the call chain"?

Comment: `__restrict__` (and `const`) is a *local* contract, it applies only to the scope of the variable thus declared. Use of loads through a non-coherent cache (`LDG` instruction, exposed with `__ldg()` intrinsic) requires a *global* contract. If the totality of a kernel's code is simple enough, one can establish the desired global property by transitive closure from local properties. Any time the compiler cannot establish with certainty that read-access data is never aliased to writable data it cannot use `LDG`, as this would break the code.

Comment: If a global function has an input which is `const __restrict__`, I don't see how any of the code the kernel calls can be allowed to write to that area in memory. Naively, you don't even have to follow any of the function calls (and if coder aliases anyway, then it's "his/her problem").

Comment: Assume the access we would like to convert into `__ldg()` is inside a `__device__` function, which is separately compiled from the `__global__` function that calls it. When generating machine for this `__device__` function, how would the compiler prove that it is safe to use an `LDG` instruction? It can't know what the calling code does.

Comment: Example: `__device__ void func (const int __restrict__ *a, int __restrict__ *b) { *b = *a; // LDG safe here? } __global__ void kernel (int __restrict__ *a, int __restrict__ *b) { func (a, b); *a *= 10; func (a, b); }`

Comment: @njuffa: Ah. Now I get it. I wasn't thinking about passing non-const as const down from the `__global__` to `__device__` functions. Maybe you could make that an answer to my first question.

Answer (score 1):

The read-only (texture) cache is not coherent with global memory. So in addition to verifying that your function does not change the data pointed at, the compiler also needs to check that the memory is not modified anywhere else in the kernel. Otherwise the function might miss changes to the data where the texture cache still contains stale data.

Comment: Should have reloaded before posting the answer - once again njuffa was faster.

Comment: So if this can be theoretically figured out, at compile time, by the wisest possible compiler (i.e. examining all code use in the kernel, checking every control path etc. - but of course assuming the basic contracts of what the kernel gets are respected) - then ldg will be used?

Comment: It will be used if the compiler can practically figure it out. Unfortunately you will have to be content with existing compilers.

Comment: ok, but that doesn't answer my question, which is what assumptions I can make in practice. What do you think of my own answer below? Is that strict enough to satisfy today's NVCC?

Comment: This is how I handle this in practice: I make all valid const and const __restrict__ annotations, then compile and check by inspecting PTX or cuobjdump -sass output that the compiler has used ldg as expected. If not, I explicitly use __ldg(). Or I use __ldg() straight away,

Comment: Note that the use of `__restrict__` frequently improves the mobility of loads, leading to better instruction schedules which leads to improved performance. IMHO `const` and `__restrict__` should be used wherever applicable, to convey a maximum of useful information to the compiler. Only if application performance is insufficient and critical would I go and inspect the SASS to see whether there are any missed opportunities for use of  `LDG` that could further boost performance. In my work that actually happens rarely, but your mileage may differ.

Answer (score 0):

Based on other comments and answers, I would venture to state the following conditions for `__ldg()` to be used on reads from a pointer `p` - each of which being sufficient (but not necessary):

**Condition A**:

> 1. `p` is a parameter of a `__global__` function.
> 2. `p` is `const __restrict__`.

**Condition B**:

> 1. `p` is a parameter of a `__device__` function `f`.
> 2. `p` is `const __restrict__`.
> 3. The function `f` is only ever called with the result of pointer arithmetic on another pointer which itself meets condition A.